# ember arrays holding global state?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to do something that i think should be dead simple. I have two models, Person and Job. A Person has many Jobs. I'm not using ember data so i'm just extending Ember.Object to create the Person and Job "classes". I'm justing using a plain 'ol array to hold the person's jobs.

If I create two people and I add a different Job to each, when I render their jobs, they both have the same jobs. I have no idea why or what the proper way to do this is.

[See this fiddle.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sepazonovi/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: null,
  jobs: []
});

App.Job = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: null
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var john = App.Person.create({name: "John Doe"});
    var rake = App.Job.create({name: "Rake leaves."});
    john.get('jobs').pushObject(rake);

    var jane = App.Person.create({name: "Jane Doe"});
    var washCar = App.Job.create({name: "Wash car."});
    jane.get('jobs').pushObject(washCar);

    // For some reason both john and jane have the same two jobs now. 
    // They should have one each.

    return [john, jane];
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is being static between different instances of the class. You will need to set a new array as the property value on the instance creation.

In Ember, object property initialization only runs once per class definition. To get around this, you must either move default value initialization into the init method or just re-define the entire array for each instance.

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: null,
  jobs: null,
  setup: function() {
    this.set('jobs', []);
  }.on('init')
});
```

[**Here is the working bin.**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yanequ/1/edit?html,js,output)